# How to give animation to layouts in single activity?

Tags: android, layout, android-animation

I have one single activity, within which I've combined severel layouts.
The thing i want to achieve is that,
when I'll open activity, the layout should come one after another from the botton and take there position below the above one.
(Like in windows 8)
How should i achieve this??
Please guide me.
Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did  you check the Google animation Guide?

1. General information about animation
   https://developer.android.com/preview/material/animations.html
2. Sample app with layout animation within an activity
   http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/Animations.zip

I hope this helps. Good luck ;)